# Is there a way to manually calculate only one workbook (with many sheets & iterative calculations) among many open workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

The closest answer I've found is to use a macro to manually calculate all sheets in a workbook but this doesn't work in my case because all sheets are interrelated and feed off of each other (the workbook includes many intentional iterative calculations).

Essentially I need a macro to simultaneously calculate all of the sheets and after hours of searching I haven't found a solution anywhere on the internet to this problem. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only options to `Calculate` are Range, Worksheet or Application.  You cannot calculate a collection of multiple Worksheets, neither by `Workbook.Worksheets.Calculate`, nor by using an Array `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetListArray).Calculate`.

If you calculate per-worksheet, your scenario will depend on which Worksheets reference each other.  If it's a linear relationship (A > B > C > D) then you can just call each worksheet once, in the correct order.

If different columns reference different sheets (A > B <> C > D <> A) then the calculation gets more complicated (e.g. A > D > A > B > C > B > C > D > A > B > C > B > C > D > A *might* get everything, depending on how many layers deep the calculations go)

If you know *exactly* what ranges reference which other sheets, then you can (in theory) refresh those in the correct order.  (A!1:1 > D!3:4 > A!2:2 > D > A > B > C!6:6 > B!9:18 > C > D > A > B > C > D)

Even using `Application.CalculationState` does not help - test the following 2 sheets:

> **Sheet1**
>   A1: 0
>   A2: =Sheet2!A1/2
>   A3: =Sheet2!A2/2
>   ~~~~
>   **Sheet2**
>   A1: =Sheet1!A1*2
>   A2: =Sheet1!A2*2

Now, change `Sheet1!A1` to `1`, and run `Sheet1.Calculate: Sheet2.Calculate:` - you'll see that the `1` populates down the sheet, but even when it reaches the bottom (all calculations complete!) `Application.CalculationState` is still `xlPending` (The status-bar says "Calculate")

This then prevents us from using a loop `While Application.CalculationState=xlPending`

Comment: Chronocidal - thanks for your help with this. I saw in another post titled "Calculate entire workbook but not all open workbooks VBA" where @Steven G recommended a solution in which selecting all sheets first and calculating afterward works. However, because I am new to VBA I didn't understand how to input his macro into the overall  macro. Here is the link to that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806643/calculate-entire-workbook-but-not-all-open-workbooks-vba

Comment: As you pointed out in your response above the calculation gets more complicated when you have different columns referencing different sheets. I have about 15 sheets in my excel file which are all interrelated and some have iterative calculations between them so it would be close to impossible to figure out the correct order.

Comment: I've just tested Steven G's code with my 2-sheet 4-equation test, and it does not actually apply the calculations correctly.  I suspect you would be best off with either calculating all workbooks, or nested loops:  `For n=1 to 10: For Each wsTMP In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets: wsTMP.Calculate: Next wsTMP: Next n` will run 10 iterations of calculating each sheet.  Set ScreenUpdating to False to speed things up, (turn it back on at the end!) and experiment with different lengths of `n` loops

Comment: I suspect you're spot on about this, wish excel would have included a shortcut just to calculate a specific workbook similar to how it has one for a specific sheet (Shift + F9). Maybe some day! I think my best bet is to calculate all open workbooks. Again, thanks for you help!